# Multi-variate regression using NumPy in Python?

Tags: python, regression

Is it possible to perform multi-variate regression in Python using NumPy?

The documentation [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html) suggests that it is, but I cannot find any more details on the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, download this ( http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/OLS?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=ols.0.2.py ) from http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/OLS

Or you can install R and a python-R link. R can do *anything*.

Comment: I'm currently using R, but I was considering making the calculation just python, for ease of sharing.

Comment: It doesn't work any longer (I changed it to conform to Python 3, so it run; but the very first test crashed Python interpreter with no error message). Anyone knows how to update it?

Answer (score 2):

The webpage that you linked to mentions [numpy.linalg.lstsq](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) to find the vector x
which minimizes `|b - Ax|`. Here is a little example of how it can be used:

First we setup some "random" data:

```
import numpy as np
c1,c2 = 5.0,2.0
x = np.arange(1,11)/10.0
y = c1*np.exp(-x)+c2*x
b = y + 0.01*max(y)*np.random.randn(len(y))
A = np.column_stack((np.exp(-x),x))
c,resid,rank,sigma = np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)
print(c)
# [ 4.96579654  2.03913202]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the [`scipy.optimize.leastsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html#scipy.optimize.leastsq) function. It's rather complicated but I seem to remember that being the thing I would look to when I wanted to do a multivariate regression. (It's been a while so I could be misremembering)