# Multivariate (polynomial) best fit curve in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, regression, scatter-plot

How do you calculate a best fit line in python, and then plot it on a scatterplot in matplotlib?

I was I calculate the linear best-fit line using Ordinary Least Squares Regression as follows:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
clf = linear_model.LinearRegression()
x = [[t.x1,t.x2,t.x3,t.x4,t.x5] for t in self.trainingTexts]
y = [t.human_rating for t in self.trainingTexts]
clf.fit(x,y)
regress_coefs = clf.coef_
regress_intercept = clf.intercept_
```

This is multivariate (there are many x-values for each case). So, X is a list of lists, and y is a single list. 
For example:

```
x = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,2,4,4,5], [2,2,4,4,1]] 
y = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

But how do I do this with higher order polynomial functions. For example, not just linear (x to the power of M=1), but binomial (x to the power of M=2), quadratics (x to the power of M=4), and so on. For example, how to I get the best fit curves from the following?

*Extracted from Christopher Bishops's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning", p.7:*

[image: Extracted from Christopher Bishops's "Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning", p.7]

Comment: Least-squares regression is still linear even when you are fitting a polynomial.  As long as the equation is a linear combination of terms (such as a polynomial), the same algorithm works.

Comment: Related: [Multi-variate regression using numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799491/multi-variate-regression-using-numpy-in-python)

Comment: Related: [Multi-variate polynomial regression with numpy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988082/multivariate-polynomial-regression-with-numpy)

Comment: Do you want to generate a formula for each set X, or generate a formula for all?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988082/multivariate-polynomial-regression-with-numpy)
provides **[a small multi poly fit library](https://github.com/mrocklin/multipolyfit)** which will do exactly what you need using numpy, and you can plug the result into the plotting as I've outlined below.

You would just pass in your arrays of x and y points and the degree(order) of fit you require into `multipolyfit`. This returns the coefficients which you can then use for plotting using numpy's polyval.

**Note:** The code below has been amended to do multivariate fitting, but the plot image was part of the earlier, non-multivariate answer.

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import multipolyfit as mpf

data = [[1,1],[4,3],[8,3],[11,4],[10,7],[15,11],[16,12]]
x, y = zip(*data)
plt.plot(x, y, 'kx')

stacked_x = numpy.array([x,x+1,x-1])
coeffs = mpf(stacked_x, y, deg) 
x2 = numpy.arange(min(x)-1, max(x)+1, .01) #use more points for a smoother plot
y2 = numpy.polyval(coeffs, x2) #Evaluates the polynomial for each x2 value
plt.plot(x2, y2, label="deg=3")
```

[image]

---

**Note:** This was part of the answer earlier on, it is still relevant if you don't have multivariate data. Instead of `coeffs = mpf(...`, use `coeffs = numpy.polyfit(x,y,3)`

For non-multivariate data sets, the easiest way to do this is probably with numpy's [`polyfit`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html):

> `numpy.polyfit(x, y, deg, rcond=None, full=False, w=None, cov=False)`
>
> Least squares polynomial fit.
>
> Fit a polynomial `p(x) = p[0] * x**deg + ... + p[deg]` of degree `deg` to points `(x, y)`. Returns a vector of coefficients p that minimises the squared error.

Comment: How does this apply to multivariate regression? Since I have multiple x-variables (5 for each case), I have a 2-dimensional array (a list of lists) for x.  My x looks like this: `[[1,2,3,4,5],[2,3,4,5,6],..]`. Inputing that into your answer, I get `TypeError: expected 1D vector for x`.

Comment: Are these separate data sets to be analysed separately, or combined? What do the y values look like?

Comment: I've edited my original question to reply to your comment. It is a single dataset. I want to regress multiple values (features, independent variables),  for example [x1,x2,x3,x4],  with a single value of y, FOR EACH CASE. Each list of x matches the corresponding y value. It's mutivariate regression.

Comment: Oh. That's a very different question to the original wording then.

Comment: @Zach Try the script linked in the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799491/multi-variate-regression-using-numpy-in-python

Comment: @jozzas Where does the module `multipolyfit` come from? Trying to import it results in an import error: `ImportError: No module named multipolyfit.multipolyfit` ...

Comment: @RolfBartstra in the linked question and answer (first link in this answer), a user has written a small utility function to do this: https://github.com/mrocklin/multipolyfit

Comment: I just noticed this question.  I've updated the organization of the repo, added a permissive open source license, and published it on PyPi.  You should be able to easy_install multipolyfit .

Comment: I am getting a TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple error for line stacked_x = numpy.array([x,x+1,x-1]).

Comment: @user200340 I fixed that error with these edits...

DELETE  "stacked_x = numpy.array([x,x+1,x-1])"                                                                                                                                                               
DELETE "coeffs = mpf(stacked_x, y, deg) "                                                                                                                                                                  
ADD "coeffs = numpy.polyfit(x,y,3)"

...Why?  See above comment: "Note: This was part of the answer earlier on,"...

Answer (score 0):

Slightly out of context because the resulting function is not a polynomial, but still interesting perhaps. One major problem with polynomial fitting is [Runge's phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon): The higher the degree, the more dramatic oscillations will occur. This isn't just constructed either but it will come back to bite you.

As a remedy, I created [smoothfit](https://github.com/nschloe/smoothfit) a while ago. It solves an appropriate least-squares problem and gives nice results, e.g.:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import smoothfit

x = [1, 4, 8, 11, 10, 15, 16]
y = [1, 3, 3, 4, 7, 11, 12]
a = 0.0
b = 17.0
plt.plot(x, y, 'kx')

lmbda = 3.0  # controls the smoothness
n = 100
u =  smoothfit.fit1d(x, y, a, b, n, lmbda)

x = np.linspace(a, b, n)
vals = [u(xx) for xx in x]
plt.plot(x, vals, "-")
plt.show()
```

[image]