# Line of best fit using axhline()

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-analysis

So I'm trying to add a line of best fit to a graph using the `plt.axhline()` feature. The code I have currently is below which is working currently but doesn't include the axhline code,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_csv('test5.csv', sep=','))
x = df["IE ratio"]
y = df["109"]
x1 = df["IE ratio"].mean()

plt.axvline(x1, 0, 1, c= 'k')
plt.scatter(x, y, s = 10)
plt.ylabel('Appearance of mutation')
plt.xlabel('IE spectrum')
plt.show()
```

I've tried to bring in the `plt.axhline()` feature but can't work out what I need to put in the bracket to get my desired output.

Here's the plot I get with a red line I've drawn on to show what I'm hoping to produce.

[Outputted graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXK2B.png)

Thanks in advance for any advice or help!

Comment: [`axhline`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axhline.html) adds a horizontal (flat) line. Definitely not what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you know of any other function or plot tool I could use?

Comment: [Perhaps similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856206/multivariate-polynomial-best-fit-curve-in-python).

Comment: Also take a look at [seaborn's regplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) which does this out of the box. It also adds a confidence interval.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the mean of `109` for a set of cuts of `IE ratio` and plotting it might get you a bit further but more information would be needed to give you more relevant advice.

```py
import numpy as np
df['109_mean'] = pd.cut(df['IE ratio'], bins=np.arange(4.6,5.6,0.01))
df.plot('IE ratio', '109_mean')
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working using old practise notebooks I have. I used the below code.

```
import matplotlib as plt
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial
x = df["IE ratio"]
y = df["44"]
xfit = np.linspace(1.3, 4.0, 30)
q = Polynomial.fit(x, y, deg=5)
plt.scatter(x, y, s = 10)
plt.plot(xfit, q(xfit), c='k')
x1 = df["IE ratio"].mean()
plt.axvline(x1, 0, 1, c= 'k')
```

Thank you for your advice guys and gals :)